# control loaded flash file using php or js

Tags: php, javascript, flash

is there a way to write a program in php or javascript that can load a flash file and interact with it? (click on buttons and such)

Comment: You might have to be mores specific, and flash app can have buttons on it, what exactly did you want to happen when those buttons are clicked?

Comment: Wow I almost posted the same question, looking for the same. Joining the thread :)

Comment: i want to do basic user interface interaction with the flash file using an API which means to press buttons, or write texts.

what do i want to happen when the buttons are clicked? what would normailly happen in the flash file itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JavaScript**
Here's a good example of Flash/JavaScript interaction [using the YouTube Chromeless Player](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/chromeless_example_1.html).

**PHP**
While you could use a query string to retrieve data from a php file or have a PHP file pre-populate FlashVars you can also [use PHP with amfPHP](http://www.amfphp.org/) for more robust database interaction.

**ActionScript**
Maybe these links will help:
[Basics of using the External Interface](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/638/1/Basics-of-using-the-ExternalInterface/Page1.html) or [External Interface](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/langref/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)

Comment: thanks for the info. i find a solution using the tools you provided.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to work server/client/flash interactions into your presentations, but for what purpose would probably be the question you should be asking. I've developed a chat client that interfaces with a jabber server through java and in turn with a Sony MMPORG game. There are many interactions between the client(browser), the server(s) and of course flash. Considering it was a flash application the interaction needed to be there in order to make the entire experience a lot more intuitive and useful for the end-user.

You can see the screenshots of this client here:
[EQ2 Web-Chat Client - Javascript/Actionscript/DHTML by DrLouie - Jabber/Java Communication by PC(Pierce Courtney)](http://www.louierd.com/soe/chat/)

Unfortunately you cannot access the live client unless you have an active Sony Station account for EverQuest 2. Keep in mind this was developed way back in 2004, so if it was possible then, it's a lot more possible today. It's a fun way to develop flash interfaces! Even more fun is finding the possibilities of flash/javascript/server interactivity, which tends to be somewhat limitless to an extent...

Answer (score 0):

Look at the ExternalInterface if you are using Flex.

http://blog.flexexamples.com/category/externalinterface/

Comment: unfortunately it's without flex.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need to be using flex to use ExternalInterface. Docs: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html
It basically let's you create functions inside your Flash app that are exposed to JavaScript allowing you to call the functions from outside the flash file. You could set up functions that mimic clicking on buttons and so forth then call them using JS.

Comment: thanks for the information. i don't think it suites my needs because i want to interact with the flash file without actually changing it. so far it seems like that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can load a flash file (.swf) into html document and make it interact with php, but! flash is the responsible of the interaction, sending data to php, so the swf file should do it, using the loadvariables() function.

good luck!